# Where can I find logs regarding the user creation?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, logs

I created a new user using `useradd` command.

I need the logs for it. Where it will be available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of logs are you looking for?

Comment: logs specifying that a new user has been created.

Comment: One way to chech if user has been created  "cat /etc/passwd | grep <user>". And please try to use adduser command instead of useradd; if you're facing some issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have created a new user look in `/var/log/auth.log`; the details are in there. I just created new user ***jim*** by running `sudo adduser jim`, for example, and this is at the end of `auth.log` (I have removed the date and host name from the start of the log):

```
 sudo: mike : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/mike ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/adduser jim
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mike(uid=1000)
 groupadd[1731]: group added to /etc/group: name=jim, GID=1001
 groupadd[1731]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=jim
 groupadd[1731]: new group: name=jim, GID=1001
 useradd[1735]: new user: name=jim, UID=1001, GID=1001, home=/home/jim, shell=/bin/bash
 passwd[1742]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for jim
 passwd[1742]: gkr-pam: couldn't update the login keyring password: no old password was entered chfn[1743]: changed user 'jim' information
 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

This particular log is very useful as it records all use of elevated privileges such as creating a user, running `Synaptic`, etc, and also notes who has done it.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.